# In MyBastis how would I map a Database Table name such as CUSTOMER_VACATION_PLAN with Java class CustomerVacationPlan?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

Our project is using **MyBatis** for persisting Java Class Objects to tables and I have a table **CUSTOMER_VACATION_PLAN** but I need to map this table name to CustomerVacationPlan or simply Vacation. In JPA I used @Table(name="") to do that.

How would I do that in MyBatis?

Answer (score 0):

In mybatis there is absolutely no coupling between table name and class name. The mapping is specified between result set (regardless of which table(s) or view(s) it is constructed from) and class.

```
<select id="selectVacations" resultType="Vacation">
   SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_VACATION_PLAN WHERE ID = #{id}
</select>
```

You need to read mybatis [mapping documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) as it is very explicit about that.